# Visual Studio 2012 don't support xslm

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012, office365

I am tried to create a new project of Excel 2013 Workbook but it's failed.

It was prompted me this message:

> Cannot open the workbook in the designer, because Visual Studio 
>   cannot find a required object for Microsoft Office Excel. To fix the problem, repair your installation of Office.

What I have done so far:

1. Uninstall / Install back office 365
2. Repair my Visual Studio 2012

But still not working!

For your information, I am used (1) Visual Studio 2012 and (2) Office 365 (Office 2013)

Hope anyone can help me on this.

Comment: owh gosh, I have updated my question back.